# one table and two comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, combobox, datatable, datasource

I have:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
adapter.Fill(ds, "Table")
dt = ds.Tables("Table")

cmbx1.DataSource = dt
cmbx1.DisplayMember = "field1"
cmbx1.ValueMember = "field2"

cmbx2.DataSource = dt
cmbx2.DisplayMember = "field1"
cmbx2.ValueMember = "field2"
```

So, when I select something from cmbx1 it is also selected in cmbx2. Why is this?

Do I need a copy of dt for cmbx2 to get the same values, but be selected independently?

Comment: Your information is really messed up but i think that if you assign the same collection to both datasoruces, both combobox's will be synchronized. Happened to me once with a WPF Datagrid, so it maybe worth trying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because they have a reference to the same object.

Use `dt.Copy()` to solve the problem.

> A new DataTable with the same structure (table schemas and constraints) and data as this DataTable.
>   If these classes have been derived, the copy will also be of the same derived classes.
>   Both the Copy and the Clone methods create a new DataTable with the same structure as the original DataTable. The new DataTable created by the Copy method has the same set of DataRows as the original table, but the new DataTable created by the Clone method does not contain any DataRows.

Comment: Yes, but I think dt.Copy() is more appropriate

Comment: Indeed. Edited my post with the MSDN-explanation why to use Copy instead of Clone.

Comment: Your welcome. Just mark the answer if it works for you. Can help other people.